# In highchart general drawing make svg label zoomable on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts, jquery-svg

```
render = this.renderer,
colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors;
                render.label("On_Mouse_Hover_Zoom",100,50).attr({'stroke-
width':1,stroke:'red'}).css({fontSize:'10px'}).add();
```

output of this code is like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59BCg.png)

Is there any way to make this label zoomable or increase label size temporary on mouse hover but it should not loose its actual size.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it simply with css:

```
  var label = this.renderer.label("On_Mouse_Hover_Zoom", 0, 0)
  .attr({
    'stroke-width': 1,
    stroke: 'red',
    id: 'your-label'
  })
  .css({
    fontSize: '10px'
  })
  .add();

  #your-label:hover text {
   fill: #efefef;
   font-size: 20px;
   transition: 0.2s;
  }
```

or use javascript but this approach is less efficient:

```
document.getElementById('your-label').onmouseenter = function() {
  label.attr({
    transform: 'scale(1.2)'
  });
}

document.getElementById('your-label').onmouseleave = function() {
  label.attr({
      transform: 'scale(1)'
  });
}
```

You can take a look at the example here: https://jsfiddle.net/wchmiel/p0c1v5w3/